# read body text of popup window in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any way we can read body of popup window and close it?

so i have page where we open popup

```
var win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
```

i need is there someway where we can read the body text of pop?

```
var bodytext = win.document.body.text;
```

please lmk, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bodytext = win.document.body.innerHTML;
```

You can only do this if the popup is from the same domain as the page that opened it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the reply.. i want to read the data from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token into my page.. is it possible?

Comment: @user3025605 : No, since that 'popup' is not on your domain, you will not be able to read the contents of it.

Comment: I clearly said you can only do it if it's in the same domain. The same-origin policy prohibits web pages from accessing contents of web pages in other domains.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = win.document.body.innerHTML;
win.document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. is it possible to read body data from differnt domain?

Comment: you can do it by CURL if you are using php.